# My emails are not being sent through google sheets appscript

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am trying to sending the email on my own address through google sheets apps script the emails are in the sent folder but i could not receive any email

here is the code for apps script

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Newsletter')
      .addItem('Send Newsletter', 'sendNewsletter')
      .addToUi();
}

function sendNewsletter() {
  // Read the HTML content from the file
  var htmlContent = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('test.html').getContent();
  
  // Define email subject
  var subject = "Stay Updated on Medical Billing Trends and Innovations";
  
  // Define list of recipients
  var recipients = [
    "hassan0102@gmail.com",
    "zail.ali284@gmail.com",
    "shabymatthew21@gmail.com",
    // Add more recipients as needed
  ];
  
  // Send email to each recipient
  recipients.forEach(function(recipient) {
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: recipient,
      subject: subject,
      htmlBody: htmlContent // Send HTML content
    });
  });
}
```